# How to Validate date dd month yyyy

Tags: jquery

I can't find a solution in google also in this site, I have tried multiple solution but there is no answer that can fit for my question.

I want to validate **03 December 2015 (USA)** (invalid date)
On my code, I will remove the last character from that string, until I reach **03 December 2015** (which is valid)

Comment: what you really want to know ?

Comment: A regular expression with capture should solve this easily.

Comment: What is your current preferred method to validate the date (maybe add some code to the question?).   Then just loop using substr/substring.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new javascript `date` object. Aslong as there is a valid date within the string, it will be able to output it in a normal readable format.

This will take in the input you want (`var date below`) and then will parse it into a new `date` object. If this fails then the below script will break.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date('03 December 2015 (USA)'); // parse in date
  var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ]; // array of month names

  var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2); // get day number with leading 0
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth(); // get month number
  var year = date.getFullYear(); // get year number

  $('.date').text(day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year); // build together and output
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="date"></span>
```

You dont need the jQuery but thats just for showing the output of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to check the date validity like:

```js
function isValidDate(date){

  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  // you need to maintain an array of full months like this.
  var d = new Date(date); // convert the date to a valid date object.
  var day = "0"+d.getDate(); // now get the valid date out of date object.
  var month = months[d.getMonth()];// now get the full month name out of month array.
  var year = d.getFullYear();// get the full year of the date object.
  
  return (day !== undefined || month !== undefined && year !== undefined)?true:false;
  // on the condition basis you can return true if date is valid otherwise false.
  
}

if(isValidDate('03 December 2015 (USA)')){
   alert('validDate');
}else{
   alert('invalid Date.');
}
```